# SXA & Item Language Fallback

Tags: sxa, language-fallback

This is for Sitecore 8.2 update-5 version and SXA 1.5 .

I have configured item fallback language in the settings of my site :

[image]

[image]

Now, we have implemented a partial design with json content that contains two contents json also.

[image]

Each content json is attached a specific variant

[image]

The problem is when we view a page in a language other than English. I do not have the same return json. However, all items in the variant definition are configured with the "enable item fallback" field checked.

Note that in the variant that returns the site tree, there are queries? I do not know if there is this notion of fallback.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to enable fallback in every partial design and page design level also.

Comment: Did you enable language fallback on your index(es)?